# Strange numbers on log-in auto complete

Tags: web-browser

I've encountered some strange numbers on the Pinterest login screen as autocomplete suggestions. Does that mean anything? For example, somebody is using my computer or account for hacking accounts, trying password combinations, etc?

Comment: What are the numbers? Do you have any other evidence that may suggest you are compromised? Why do you think auto complete is an indicator of anything?

Comment: Go to your browser settings and have a look at the saved autocomplete settings. Is the number familiar?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MPnC46b

Here it is.

Also, they are so many that i'm nearly sure i wasn't the one who entered them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, you are almost certainly not being hacked.

This looks like standard behaviour for a browser. You probably typed those numbers into a site somewhere and now your browser is trying to be clever by thinking that Pinterest has similar text inputs to the previous site you put the numbers into, and suggesting you type the numbers into the text input on this new site.

---

To see exactly what is happening you can view the auto-fill data for your browser and you should be able to see those numbers:

- ### [Chrome](https://superuser.com/a/884033/678387)

  (I had to change my profile for the location of my "Web Data" file `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\[your profile]\Web Data`)
- ### [Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550680/6836586)

Comment: If you know of a way to view auto-fill data in other browsers please feel free to [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/185451/edit) the question